# Where to buy a 4G Telkomsel sim card in Indonesia?

Tags: cellphones, indonesia, communication, mobile-operators, phone-networks

I have been seeing advertising about the Telkomsel 4G sim card but I'm not able to find any place to buy it.

I tried many small resellers but they only have 3G SIM cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy the 4G SIM card in Telkomsel Grapari in Jakarta and Bali, read [here](http://internet.telkomsel.com/4g-lte/promopaket) under "Terms and Conditions". You can find the address list [here](http://www.telkomsel.com/customer-service/lokasi-layanan/370-GraPARI---GraPARIkios---Plasa-GraPARI.html).

Comment: Are Graparis some kind of official Telkomsel shops?

Comment: Yes, the building is usually in red color - the Telkomsel color, so you can't miss it. Unfortunately I don't have any experience buying the 4G SIM card there, but I'm sure they can help you.